# In Shopify Private app, Proxy URL Redirect to App's Server URL

Tags: laravel, shopify, shopify-app

I am working on Shopify private app in the Laravel Framework. In my app, I have added a proxy URL. But when I am trying to open my proxy URL then It will redirect to me on my app server URL.

Here's the screenshot my partner account:-

[image]

For Example:- 
Whenever I tried to open proxy URL:- https://test.myshopify.com/a/test

It will redirect to my app server URL:-
https://test.devserver.co.in/shopify/test?shop=test.myshopify.com&path_prefix=%2Fa%test&timestamp=1559210902&signature=bed7eb24d4a9278021a12535df9e38749a333a9dd33e7164fb66c113a2a00a0e

Please help me with this.
Thanks

Comment: are you using any package for Shopify authentication?

Comment: @bhavinjr No, I have created a custom app installation process as per Shopify OAuth guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually callback to your proxy URL like https://test.myshopify.com/a/fizzbuzz

Instead you do a POST or a GET to /a/fizzbuzz with some parameters (or not). In other words, it is as if you are doing a POST or GET to something local to the Shopify store itself. There is nothing to identify your actual proxy App.

Perhaps this is your simple problem. Shopify will take your POST or GET, and proxy it for you to the right endpoint in your App, with security.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is that mean I can't directly open proxy URL by a hit in browser? I can open proxy URL programmatically and also have passed some data on this URL. Am I right?

Comment: If you choose to go the hit in browser route, which is https://test.myshopify.com/a/fizzbuzz then what will happen is Shopify will send a GET to your App endpoint, and you will return Application/Liquid and a string of Liquid so that Shopify will display that as {{content_for_layout}}.

Comment: If I directly open proxy URL in the browser then it will redirect me to app server's URL which I have mentioned above in question. I think this will happens in laravel because of my app is in laravel

Comment: I dunno what you are doing wrong, but if your App is rendering some authentication on that route from within your App, then you need to decouple that route from authentication. Instead, allow your route end point for the proxy to use the security checking pattern with the embedded headers from Shopify to validate the incoming call.

Comment: Again, Thanks for the reply. But I have already created a different route for proxy. There is no need for authentication to open the route. How I can use the security checking pattern with the embedded headers from Shopify to validate the incoming call? Would you please help me with this.

Comment: POST requests are not working for me, any insight? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60978973/shopify-app-with-proxy-extension-post-requests-not-working