# Shopify app with proxy extension POST requests not working

Tags: ajax, shopify

Following the guide here: https://shopify.dev/tutorials/display-data-on-an-online-store-with-an-application-proxy-app-extension

GET requests are working fine for me.

But when I try to do a POST request, my parameters are not coming through.

I'm building a simple wishlist app, where a user can click on a heart on a product and it adds it to a database.

So my code, when they click the heart, looks something like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '/apps/wishlist/save',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            shop: shop,
            customerId: customerId,
            productId: productId
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
          console.info(data);
        }
    });
```

When I inspect this post in Network tab in Chrome Dev Tools, the original POST is hitting a 301, then Shopify is creating a GET request to the original URL with different/missing parameters that look like this:

```
shop: example.myshopify.com
path_prefix: /apps/wishlist
timestamp: 1585769299
signature: examplesignature
```

If I change my original AJAX request to a GET, then my original parameters are passed as expected.

Are POST requests not allowed here?

Comment: POST requests are allowed. How does the `/save` processing script look like?

Comment: What framework do you use for your app? Is there a way to check that i.e. go to your store, preview theme link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add `/` to the end of your `url` i.e. change it to `/apps/wishlist/save/`.

Comment: F my life, that was it.

Answer (score 1):

Just to give a clearification.
[Vladimir answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60979510/12209219) works, why?
It seems that Shopify changed their authentication flow for some POSTs request.
You have to send requests without cookies or you can send requests with `X-Shopify-Access-Token` header and use your app's password for it. They should work both but there are some cases of use that doesn't permit you to send request without cookie or only uses basic auth (depending on wich method and software you use to send request). Shopify's devs are not crazy of course, this was implemented due to avoid some kind of hackers attack based on specific attacking methods, but maybe it should be better clearly specified in their documentation. Even if the solution explained above should be preferred, as said it could not work in some cases so the [Vladimir 's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60979510/12209219) is a valid alternative (you could also add a dot at the end of the URL so for example: www.example.com./etc/etc), this because this way "blocks" the cookie seending.
You can know more about that following Sopify's community discussion [here](https://community.shopify.com/c/API-Announcements/Shopify-now-prevents-HTTP-Basic-Auth-POST-requests-that-have/m-p/292986)